# Searching for a string in Dynamic generated HTML in the Chrome Developer Tools Elements Panel

Tags: html, search, dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to search in the developer tools of Chrome in Elements Panel where some dynamic generated HTML is displayed for a bit of code. No way... I don't understand why something so simple doesn't works...
Somebody has a tip or an explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

We would appreciate it if you could come up with a test case and file a bug at http://new.crbug.com with the Feature-DevTools label.

You may also want to make sure that you are using the latest available version of Google Chrome to see if the bug has already been fixed (check the number of matches next to the search box after hitting Enter/Return.)